# text is perpendicular to line when using sloped option tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to add some text over top of a line that follows along the line.  I've read about the sloped option which you can pass to a node defined along the line which seems like it should do what I want but instead it is doing the exact opposite (putting the text perpendicular to the line instead of along it).  A MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,plotmarks,positioning,angles}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{120}


\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=1in,y=0.75in,z=-1in,>=stealth']

    \coordinate (mapP) at (1,-2,3);

    \coordinate (map) at (4,6,2);


    \draw[dashdotted,->,blue,thick] (mapP) -- node[midway,anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt,text=blue,sloped]{$\textbf{v}_{sc-map}$} (map);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This outputs something like
￼[image: note how the text is almost perpendicular to the line]

My guess is that the issue is probably the cm option passed to the tikz picture (and I believe this guess is correct because when I remove that option the text displays correctly) but this is obviously part of a much larger project and I don't really want to have to try and figure out how to adjust everything without that cm option as the rest of the project is pretty much done.

My question is, does anyone know how I can fix this or another easy way I can get the text to follow the line?  I know about the rotate option but I'd rather not have to figure out the required rotation angles because I have to label a good number of lines this way.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the `cm` setting? You could also modify the `x` `y` and `z` ones to get a similar effect without affecting the `sloped` style...try with `x=1in,y=-0.75in,z=-1in` and removing `cm`

Comment: That seems to do similar to what I want and in the future I will probably try to do that, but there are a lot of other hacks in the rest of the document based on the way it is set up now that I don't really want to take the time to fix.  Thanks for the suggestion though (I started this project when I was just learning tikz so there are some questionable things I do throughout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is your wish so how the picture comes is your luck `;-)`. Add the `transform shape` to `tikzpicture` options so that the transformations (`cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)}`) you are imposing are applied to node text too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,plotmarks,positioning,angles}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{120}


\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=1in,y=0.75in,z=-1in,>=stealth',transform shape]

    \coordinate (mapP) at (1,-2,3);

    \coordinate (map) at (4,6,2);


    \draw[dashdotted,->,blue,thick] (mapP) -- node[midway,anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt,text=blue,sloped]{$\textbf{v}_{sc-map}$} (map);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @HarishKumar.  That mostly works although I had to make some adjustments.  First, instead of adding the transform shape option to the tikzpicture environment and thus applying it to everything I just added it to the lines I was labelling.  Second, there was still something weird going on where the text was upside down so I had to add a rotate=180 option as well.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `[tdplot_main_coords,cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)}` will work per my test.

Code as below:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing,plotmarks,positioning,angles}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,x=1in,y=0.75in,z=-1in,>=stealth']
    \coordinate (mapP) at (1,-2,3);
    \coordinate (map) at (4,6,2);
    \draw[dashdotted,->,blue,thick] (mapP) -- node[midway,anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt,text=blue,sloped]{$\textbf{v}_{sc-map}$} (map);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks lucky1928.  I had realized that this was the issue, but as I said in the post, the problem is I need that cm for the rest of my diagram, so deleting it doesn't help me.